# How should this sentence be punctuated and why?

Tags: punctuation

How should this sentence be punctuated and why?  "The children enter the school their new uniforms shining."

Answer (score 2):

Offset "their new uniforms shining" with a comma because the sentence is complete with out the modifying phrase.